# Firebase DataSnapshot Out Of Memory Error

Tags: android, firebase

I have only two elements in Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://incandescent-torch-4.firebaseio.com/profiles");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
            if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()){
                for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Profile profile = child.getValue(Profile.class);
                    profiles.add(profile);
                }
                chatsAdapter.addList(profiles);
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

In debug I always get:

> dataSnapshot: Method threw 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError' exception.
>   Cannot evaluate com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.toString()

`JSON` has only 2 objects and 2 images 600 Kb each. I save them as Base64.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here. You're allocating more memory than is available. The solution is to allocate less memory, for example by putting the images elsewhere in your data tree (so that you end up loading them one by one) or even better: storing the images on a dedicated image/file storage service.

Comment: *Firebase just released a new feature called [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). This allows you to upload images and other non-JSON data to a dedicated storage service. We highly recommend that you use this for storing images, instead of storing them as base64 encoded data in the JSON database. That will likely also reduce the memory problems your app is having.*